# How to implement 'follow' functionality on a blog author

Tags: python, django

I have a blog app that works pretty well.  However I want to expand its functionality to include an option for users to follow authors.  I created a class FeedListView has a get_queryset function but i dont know how to use this to return the authors the logined in user follows.

my FeedListView looks like this:

```
class FeedListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/feed_posts.html' # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = Post.objects.filter(author__followers=user)
        return queryset
        # self.user = self.get_object()
        # return Post.objects.filter(author__followers=user)
```

The model (User) like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followed_by', symmetrical=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

the url.py is:

```
path('feed/', FeedListView.as_view(), name='feed_posts'),
```

If i can get it to the state where when i navigate to the url the posts only by the followed users are displayed I would be overjoyed.

But I need some guidance on how this query set works as im a bit lot here.

The error i get at the moment is user is not defined.

```
NameError at /feed/
name 'user' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/feed/
Django Version: 2.2.4
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'user' is not defined
Exception Location: C:\django-projects\blogger\django_blogger\blogger\blog\views.py in get_queryset, line 86
```

====
EDIT

I changed the get_queryset to the following:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        follow_data = []
        following_me_data = []
        theUser = Profile.objects.filter(user_id__exact=self.request.user.id)
        theFollowers = theUser[0].follows.all()
        follow_data.append(theFollowers)
        following_me = theUser[0].followed_by.all()
        following_me_data.append(following_me)
        print(f'I follow: {follow_data}')
        print(f'{following_me_data} follows me')

        return theFollowers
```

with the template being:

```
<h1 class="mb-3">Followed users: ({{ page_obj.paginator.count }})</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
    <article class="media content-section">
    <a href="{% url 'user-posts' post.user %}">{{ post.user }}</a>
    </article>
    {% endfor %}
```

So I have been able to get this working with displaying the people that I follow.  I need to modify the follow data to be an arary of array so i can return the following and follers.

But how do i return the post of these people that I am following?

Comment: can you show the error traceback

Comment: Its simple that the variable user is used without declaring and defining it.Is the user specified in the line is authenticated? and logged in?

Comment: In `FeedListView. get_queryset` you access to user variable but it's not defined yet. You could try `self.request.user` instead, django set logged in user into user attribute of request object, so let's try.

Comment: Hi @ToanQuocHo I tried that but now get the error: FieldError at /feed/
Related Field got invalid lookup: follows  ```def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = Post.objects.filter(author__follows=self.request.user)
        return queryset```

Comment: Hi @rogue_particle, currently your Post model have a field is `author` right? and it linked to `Profile` model. If its true, then I think you should change the query to: `Post.objects.filter(author__in=user__profile__follows)`, because you want to get a list of authors which the current user following, and find posts which have author inside that following list.

Comment: I tried that just now but i get an error name 'user__profile__follows' is not defined

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean self.request.user.profile.follows. Complete query is in this case is: `Post.objects.filter(author__in=self.request.user.profile.follows)`

Comment: Hi @ToanQuocHo I fixed the issue witht he code i posted in teh question edit section but im getting an error with the template in that when I try to print out the blog entries - the one the user follow i get :   NoReverseMatch at /feed/
Reverse for 'user-posts' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(?P<username>[^/]+)$']   this is teh code it doesn't like    ```  <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>```

Comment: @rogue_particle, Could you please add your template into the question also? It could help a lot because there is nothing related to `user-posts` on your question.